# on click outside of link close jquery dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a mega menu plugin

plugin link : https://codyhouse.co/demo/mega-dropdown/index.html

this drop down closing only when we click on drop down link button. but I want to close this drop down when we click outside of the link (body or html).

hear is my website link : http://btssystem.com/new-tricky

At the right side of the top menu 
I have a My account drop down. I want to close this drop down when we click on outside of menu or body or html.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi kindly paste this code in head section

```
<script>
    $(document).mouseup(function (e)
{

  var container = $('.cd-dropdown, .cd-dropdown-trigger');


  if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        if($('.cd-dropdown, .cd-dropdown-trigger').hasClass('dropdown-is-active'))
$('.cd-dropdown, .cd-dropdown-trigger').removeClass('dropdown-is-active');

    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working Perfect. I just copy and paste your code and it is working as charm... I am very happy. Thank you soooo much. check the link now : http://btssystem.com/new-tricky/

Comment: It's working..Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).click( function(){
    $('.main-nav').hide();
});
```

Comment: I have Updated your code but it's not working perfectly.

Comment: I have updated your code but not working perfectly. see the link:http://btssystem.com/new-tricky/

Comment: if you do that it wont change the cross of the menu, since you dont use the "mega menu plugin".

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering a click on the link:

```
$(document).click( function(){
    $('div.cd-dropdown-wrapper > a').trigger('click')
});
```

Comment: with that script it will keep opening and closing the menu whenever user clicks anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('*').not('div.cd-dropdown-wrapper > a').click( function(){
    if ($('.div.cd-dropdown-wrapper > a').hasClass('dropdown-is-active')) $('div.cd-dropdown-wrapper > a').trigger('click');
});
```

I'm not sure if it will be final solution, I think you are playing with your page, since I have some strange behaviours when trying things there, but I hope it can help you at least to go in this direction